# Is it possible to create 'invisible' project using Visual Studio addin?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, plugins

I have an idea to create some sort of extended Immediate Window VS plugin. I've noticed that when I want to test something (like new Regex or DB reqest) I tend to create new console app for this. The idea is to create project that is not included in solution and references current project and has all `using` directives from current file. So I'll have all advantages of code editor: usings (no full class names), syntax highliting, IntelliSense, multiline commands, other plugins (R#/CR).

Is this possible?

Comment: It's not tests of my code, it's some testing about what I'm going to write. Something like "Does that 3-rd party function work like I think it does?" or figuring out how to use some external class

Comment: "Something like "Does that 3-rd party function work like I think it does?" or figuring out how to use some external class " - they are both use cases for writing unit tests.

Comment: And what if I need to run some utils with output like `MyUtils.GenerateNewHash()` for one time? Create unit test for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option A: Write those in a test-project added to your solution

Option B: Create a console application added to your solution

Create a build-script that only builds the projects you want to give to your customers.

To gain some ideas: look at http://mvcstarter.codeplex.com/ (point 9)